After a server restart, an Odoo 16 nested tree view displays a blank page initially, but the data only becomes visible after clicking on the page
I am implementing a tree view in a tree view to display data. In the job_description model. we have a details_id that links the job description to the job details stored in another table also included below
from odoo import models, fields
class WorkPlan(models.Model):
    _name = 'job.description'
    _description = 'Job Description'

    job_id = fields.Many2one('hr.job', string='Job Position', readonly=True)
    job_purpose = fields.Text(string='Job Purpose', required=True)
    details_ids = fields.One2many('job.description.details', 'job_description_id', string='Details')

from odoo import models, fields


class JobDescriptionDetails(models.Model):
    _name = 'job.description.details'
    _description = 'Job Description Details'

    key_result_area = fields.Text(string='Key Result Area', required=True)
    principal_accountabilities = fields.Text(string='Principal Accountabilities', required=True)
    job_description_id = fields.Many2one('job.description', string='Work Plan')

The following is the xml page that handles the logic. When adding information. I don't have a problem, it is saving and when I go to check on a particular job it is showing. However when I restart the server the when I go to the record it is showing that it has data but the table is blank. More information included below.
The xml file that handles the view
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="view_job_description_details_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">job.description.details.tree</field>
            <field name="model">job.description.details</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree editable="bottom">
                    <field name="key_result_area"/>
                    <field name="principal_accountabilities"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record id="view_job_description_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">job.description.form</field>
            <field name="model">job.description</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                    <field name="job_id"/>
                    <field name="job_purpose"/>
                    <field name="details_ids" widget="one2many_list" options="{'no_create': True}">
                        <tree string="Details" editable="bottom" view_id="view_work_plan_goals_tree"/>
                    </field>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>

Below is how it is coming up when i restart the server
after server restart
Below when I click on any of the headers after restart
after clicking either add line or the headers
I tried computing the details_id fields using the following code but it makes the data in the details_ids table to disappear completely
class JobDescription(models.Model):
    _name = 'job.description'
    _description = 'Job Description'

    job_id = fields.Many2one('hr.job', string='Job Position', readonly=True)
    job_purpose = fields.Text(string='Job Purpose', required=True)
    details_ids = fields.One2many('job.description.details', 'job_description_id', string='Details', compute='_compute_details_ids')

    @api.depends('job_id')
    def _compute_details_ids(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.job_id:
                record.details_ids = self.env['job.description.details'].search([('job_description_id', '=', record.job_id.id)])
            else:
                record.details_ids = self.env['job.description.details']

    def read(self, fields=None, load='_classic_read'):
        result = super(JobDescription, self).read(fields, load)
        self._compute_details_ids()
        return result


You need to run job_description_id before details_ids since details_ids is dependant on job_description_id

For me it looks like that you have a loz empty records for model job.description.details. But i'm wondering why only 7 entries are shown at all. All in all very weird behavior. Where does the one2many_list widget is coming from? I don't know of that widget. And why is details_ids defined so unusual? You define no_create but make the tree editable="bottom".

Hello @jdweng Thanks for the update. I found that it was the way I was implementing the xml file to render the view. indeed  details_ids was running first. Had to do a overhaul

hello @CZoellner thanks for the observation. just found out that I was suppose to use the one2many widget. indeed it contributed to the wired behaviour
